# "Comical" v. "Comedic"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Is there any semantic distinction between the words *comedic* and *comical*?

I usually use the former to describe people and the latter to describe things, situations, etc.

Comment: Why do you think they are interchangeable, in the first place? Each has its significance. What is the difference between them that you have understood from the dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

***Comedic*** has two definitions; one is *of or relating to comedy*, the other is the same as what ***comical*** means: funny.

From MW:

> [Comedic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comedic)
>
> 1
>   :  of or relating to comedy
>
> 2
>   :  comical
>
> [Comical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comical)
>
> 1 obsolete :  of or relating to comedy
>
> 2
>   :  causing laughter especially because of a startlingly or unexpectedly humorous impact

So you would say someone has *comedic* talent because they can produce *comical* acts.

Comment: Since one definition of comedic is comical also, does it follow that all definitions of comical are inherited to comedic?

Comment: @LesterNubla I am unfamiliar with the expression *inherited to* -- can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi @Kris. I mean, "comedic" also acquires all the definitions of "comical".

Comment: @Kris A word contained in another word. All comedic things are comical, but no all comical things are comedic. Similar to how all insecticides are pesticides, but no all pesticides are insecticides.

Comment: @Cruncher I was referring to the expression *inherited to* -- that verb doesn't (cannot) normally take the preposition *to*.

Comment: @LesterNubla --ditto--

Answer (score 1):

"COMIC" is the older form of "relating to comedy".
It may apply to either art-forms or life events, since it was originally used to describe a form of DRAMA, which is an art that imitates real life.
In some scholarly references, the word is still used with it's classical meaning, which is the logical opposite to "TRAGIC".

Since the word "COMIC" has become widely used by synecdoche to describe any art that was funny (including satire, which can be tragic in structure), came the neologisms "COMICAL" and "TRAGICAL", to avoid confusion. "COMIC", then, became permenantly attached to other meanings: it now relates mainly to sequential graphics, but it still evokes the sense of "art supposed to be funny" (hence the point of the term "graphic novel"). COMICAL and TRAGICAL, then, still relate to the structural shape of comedy and tragedy, and can still be applied to either art or real life events.

"COMEDIC", finally, is a more recent neologism that people have been using to avoid even further confusion. Some people dislike the word on the basis that it is a neologism - and that there are already TWO other words that can express what it means.

I, however, would take notice that COMIC and COMICAL still relate to TRAGIC and TRAGICAL, while COMEDIC doesn't have a "TRAGEDIC" to oppose it. What this means is that COMIC and COMICAL still relate to aspects of structure: they apply to either life events or literature that doesn't end tragically, or doesn't evoke pity from an audience. The word COMEDIC, then, implies an allusion to comedy in tone or style, rather then in structure. It doesn't relate to life events, but only to writing styles. The more accurate substitute for COMEDIC, then, is not COMIC or COMICAL, but "HUMOROUS":

"Comedic writing style" = "humorous writing style" / 
"Comedic sketch show" = "humorous sketch show" / 
"Comedic news" = "humorous news"